# Handling Aggregate Exceptions in Service Fabric

Tags: c#, exception, asp.net-core, azure-service-fabric

Let's say I have a Web API service that calls my user Service to return user profile information etc..

`UserProfileService` can throw `UserNotFoundException`. When thrown, it is serialized and sent as an inner exception in an `AggregateException` which can be caught in the calling method. This service uses Service Fabric's service remoting for RPCing.

My WebAPI is calling my service like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var profile = await _userService.GetProfileAsync(int id);
        return Json(profile);
    } catch (AggregateException ae)
    {
        // Here I want to call NotFound() if `UserNotFoundException`
        //   was thrown, otherwise...
        return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
    }
}
```

So a couple of questions here:

1. What do I do to handle expected exceptions?

Naively I'd do something like this:

```
try { /* ... */ } catch (AggregateException ae)
{
    foreach(var e in ae.InnerExceptions)
    {
        if (e is UserNotFoundException)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
    }

    return errorResponse ?? StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
}
```

But the trouble with this is, if there are multiple exceptions only one will "win". And, I believe - although there is no guarantee, that the earliest added `Exception`s will have priority, as they'll have a lower index in `InnerExceptions`. Am I over thinking this, and would this solution be fine? The only time my custom exceptions will be thrown are when I know they should be thrown, surely?

This leads me to my other question:

2. Under what circumstances would you retrieve several exceptions in an `AggregateException`.

Is it when you have `Task a` calling `Task b` calling a `Task c`, `c` throws, `b` doesn't throw, `a` throws, you'd get aggregate exception containing `a` and `c`'s exceptions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll answer your questions backwards:

2) `AggregateException` has a [contructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383498(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows an `IEnumerable<Exception>` as parameter. This is how it can contain multiple inner exceptions. This means that your aggregate exception won't contain more than one inner exception unless you explicitly throw an `AggregateException` with multiple inner exceptions. Say you have a `Task a` calling `Task b` calling `Task c`. If `c` throws an exception, which is not caught in `a` or `b`, `a` would throw an `AggregateException` with an inner `AggregateException` with an inner exception thrown by `c`.

1) Your example works just fine. If you want it a bit shorter you could catch it by inner exception:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is UserNotFoundException)
{
    // ...
}
catch (AggregateException ex) when (ex.InnerException is SomeOtherException)
{
    // ...
}
```

You could also catch them with some if-statements like you did in your example:

```
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (AggregateException ex)
{
    if (ex.InnerException is UserNotFoundException)
    {
        // ...
    }
    else if (ex.InnerException is SomeOtherExeption)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much, that has cleared things up for me immensely!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to throw exceptions in all relevant classes, and to only catch those at the web service, that reports one error message to the web service caller. Keep the exception handling as simple as possible.

To rephrase: if something goes wrong in whatever code, just `throw new Exception()` with a string indicating what happened and where. The only place where you do `try/catch` is in the `[httpget] Get()`.

If you really know what you are doing, you could implement serialized exceptions stuff, but then you would not ask about that here :-)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, sorry :(

Comment: From what I understand, when you do an RPC using Service Fabric's Remoting library, exceptions thrown in remote services are serialized, sent over the wire, and deserialized into an `AggregateException` by the service Fabric runtime/libraries -- If that makes anything clearer!